# need some correction in Typewriter effect in flash.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm using the typewriting effect in that I need to reduce the speed of word printing. I don't know how to reduce the speed of content printing.

This is the code

```
    var format : TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    format.size = 14;
    format.font = "Arial";
    format.bold = true;
    format.color = 0x00000;

    var _textField : TextField = new TextField();
    _textField.width = 400;
    _textField.height = 200;
    _textField.selectable = false;
    _textField.wordWrap = true;
    _textField.defaultTextFormat = format;
    _textField.x = _textField.y =10;
    addChild(_textField);


    var _textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("text.txt"));
    _textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Init, false, 0, true);


    function Init(e:Event):void
    {
      var _text = e.target.data; 
      _letters = _text.split('');

      addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Write, false, 0, true); 
    }

    function Write(e:Event):void
    {
      if (_counter < _letters.length)
      {
             _textField.appendText(_letters[_counter]); 
             _counter++; 
      }

}
```

Comment: I recommend you looking into the `Timer` class as well. I prefer it over setInterval as well as "framing" it. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're using an EnterFrame event you could just reduce the FPS of the SWF, but that probably is not what you want as it would reduce the speed of everything in the SWF not just the textfield printing.

Alternatively you can just maintain some counter variable to keep track of frames and only appendText every 10 frames or so. For example:

```
var currFrame:int = 0;
//...
function Write(e:Event):void
{
    currFrame++;//increase the counter
    if(currFrame > 10)
    {//only write a letter every 10 frames
        currFrame = 0;//reset the counter
        if (_counter < _letters.length)
        {
            _textField.appendText(_letters[_counter]); 
            _counter++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Adjust that '10' to change the speed (larger numbers = slower)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see the variable _counter declared anywhere in the code.
That said, they are a few ways to make it go slower, this is one of the possibilities.

If the "_counter" var is smaller than the length of the string => add a letter.

So to make this go slower you can say:

If the "_counter" var is smaller than the length of the string => wait 2seconds and then add a letter.

You can do this, for example, with the setInterval function:

[www.ilike2flash.com/2009/07/time-delay-in-actionscript-3.html](http://www.ilike2flash.com/2009/07/time-delay-in-actionscript-3.html)

so your code will look something similar to this:

```
    var _prevCounter = "";
        function Write(e:Event):void
    {
        if (_counter < _letters.length && _counter != _prevCounter)
        {
            setInterval(addLetter, 3000);
            _counter++;
        }
    }

    function addLetter()
    {
        _textField.appendText(_letters[_counter]);
    }
```

**This was not tested and could cause some errors, never copy/paste if you don't understand what you are copy/pasting!**

Good luck & hope this helps you on your way!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) event instead of the ENTER_FRAME event. You can define the "speed of word printing" as the timer delay.

```
const DELAY_BETWEEN_LETTERS:int = 100; // here you are setting 100 ms between each letter output
var timer:Timer = new Timer(DELAY_BETWEEN_LETTERS);
function Init(e:Event):void
{
  var _text = e.target.data; 
  _letters = _text.split('');

  timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Write);
  timer.start();
}

function Write(e:TimerEvent):void
{
  if (_counter < _letters.length)
  {
         _textField.appendText(_letters[_counter]); 
         _counter++; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use timers like in the following example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TextEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            var textField:TypewriterTextField = new TypewriterTextField();
            textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            textField.border = true;
            addChild(textField);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.utils.Timer;

class TypewriterTextField extends TextField {

    public function TypewriterTextField() {

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

    }// end function

    private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

    }// end function

    private function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {

        e.preventDefault();

        if (stage.focus == this) {

            var char:String = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);

            if (char.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9\s\n]/) ||  e.charCode == 8) {

                var timer:CustomTimer = new CustomTimer(e.charCode, 500, 1);
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
                timer.start();

            }// end if

        }// end if

    }// end function

    private function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {

        var customTimer:CustomTimer = e.target as CustomTimer;
        customTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);

        var charCode:uint = customTimer.object as uint;
        var char:String = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

        if (char.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9\s\n]/)) {

            this.text += char;

        }
        else {

            this.text = this.text.slice(0, -1);

        }// end else if

    }// end function

}// ende class

class CustomTimer extends Timer {

    private var _cbject:Object;

    public function get object():Object {

        return this._cbject;

    }// end function

    public function CustomTimer(object:Object, delay:Number, repeatCount:int = 0) {

        super(delay, repeatCount);

        _cbject = object;

    }// end function

}// end class
```